# Diagonalizable and nilpotent operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field and let $L:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear operator. Show that there exist a diagonalizable operator $D$ and a nilpotent operator $N$ such that $L=DN=ND$. Is the result true over $\mathbb{R}$? Prove or disprove.

Please HELP!

Comment: If $L=DN=ND$, then $L^k=D^kN^k=0$ for large enough $k$.

Answer (score 2):

The correct statement is $L = D +N$ where $D$ is diagonalizable and
$N$ is nilpotent with $DN = ND.$ Hints:

$1).\ $ Write  $V = U_1 \oplus\cdots \oplus U_m$ where $U_k=\ker(L-\lambda_kI)^n$ and $\lambda_1,\cdots, \lambda_m$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $L$ and prove that each $U_k$ is $L$-invariant.

$2).\ $ Prove that $(L-\lambda_kI)|_{U_k}$ is nilpotent.

$3).\ $ Show that the projections $E_k:V\to U_k$ all commute with $L,$ that $\sum^m_{k=1}E_k=I$ and that $E_kE_j=\delta_{kj}.$

$4).\ $ To finish , define $D=\sum^m_{k=1}\lambda_kE_k$ and $N=\sum^m_{k=1}(L-\lambda_kI)E_k$ and prove the original claim by direct calculation.

Comment: Can you provide a good reference where that is shown?

Comment: [Here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.61.3927&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is an elementary proof and some examples.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out!