# Question about sum of diagonalizable and nilpotent operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear operator and $V$a finite dimensional vector space over $F$. Suppose that $m_T = (x- \lambda_1)^{m_1} \cdots (x - \lambda_k)^{m_k}$. Show that there is a diagonalizable operator $D:V \to V$ and a nilpotent operator $N: V\to V$ s.t $T = D+N$ and $DN= ND$. Futhermore, prove that $D$ and $N$ are polynomials in $T$.

I know that some variations of this question has asked before here:

[Diagonalizable and nilpotent operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455338/diagonalizable-and-nilpotent-operators)

However, a tried to solve my way, so I have questions about my solution:

Since $m_t$ has that form in $F[x]$ then $p_T$ does, that is, $T$ admit a jordan canonical form, call $J$.

Since each block of $J$ is sum of a diagonalizable and a nilpotent operator we have $J = D' + N'$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $N$ is nilpotent.

Therefore, for each basis $B$ of $V$ there exists $P$ s.t $[T]_{B} = P^{-1} J P = P^{-1}(D'+N')P = P^{-1}D' P + P^{-1}N' P$.

Now take $D:V \to V$,  where $[D]_{B}= [P^{-1}D'P]$ and $N: V \to V$, where $[N]_{B} = [P^{-1}N' P]$. So we have $D$ diagonalizable and $N$ nilpotent.

But $ND = P^{-1} N' D' P \neq P^{-1}D'N'P = DN$ (it's easy to show a counter example). Where is my wrong?

Also, How can I prove that $D$ and $N$ are polynomials in $T$?

Comment: I can't really help here, but just in case someone doesn't know this, this might help look for helpful info: this result is called the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition.

Comment: one issue I see is that Jordan form is only guaranteed when over an algebraically closed field such as $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: but by assumption the minimal polynomial $m_T$  has in the linear form in $F$, so $P_T$ does. Then there is a Jordan form.

Comment: @guy3141 The Jordan form exists if the minimal polynomial can be factorized into linear factors. Over $\mathbb C$ this is always possible due to the fundamental theorem of algebra. But it's the factorization of the minimal polynomial that actually matters.

Comment: @Joãonani $D'$ and $N'$ should commute if you obtain them from the Jordan form. Would you care to show your counter example? As a side note, doing it this way kinda defeats the point. The Jordan normal form is usually obtained by showing the statement you want to prove and then translating it into matrix form. Using the normal form to show that your statement is true would be circular reasoning.

Comment: Now I see, I've made a mistake in my counter example, $D'$ and $N'$ commutes. But how can I prove that $D$ and $N$ are polynomials in $T$?